# can anybody help i have got an error NameError: name 'bgr_image' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

/project$ python server.py

2018-05-24 16:52:28.151418: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "server.py", line 108, in 
    predictions = sess.run(prob_tensor, {input_node: [bgr_image] })

NameError: name 'bgr_image' is not defined

Comment: As i used the custom vision model and docs from microsoft azure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/export-model-python

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9101 Nothing we can do.

Comment: ok @matias Valdengro the error has resolved just replace bgr_image to augmented_image

predictions = sess.run(prob_tensor, {input_node: [bgr_image] }) to predictions = sess.run(prob_tensor, {input_node: [augmented_image] })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error has resolved just replace bgr_image to augmented_image

predictions = sess.run(prob_tensor, {input_node: [bgr_image] }) to predictions = sess.run(prob_tensor, {input_node: [augmented_image] })